# GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx(), ReadDirectoryChangesW()

Tags: c++, winapi, iocp, readdirectorychangesw

I am using `GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx()` and `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` to try to receive notifications of changes to multiple filesystem hierarchies.

I noticed that I would receive completion packets with error 0x10C when there would be a lot of changes at once. This error code wasn't anywhere in the header files I'd included and wasn't in the documentation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx ). A little digging later, I find out that it's `STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR` defined in `ntstatus.h`. Neither STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR is mentioned in the documentation nor is the necessity of including ntstatus.h. MSDN indicates that it should have been `ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR`. So I am wondering, is this a bug in the documentation or perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @HansPassant, it is the error code which is passed in with the i/o completion packet at lpOverlapped->Internal.

Comment: How do *you* get the error code for a failed operation using `GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx()`, then?

Comment: @HansPassant I don't call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`, I call `GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx()`. I don't call `GetLastError()` when `GetQueuedCompletionstatusEx()` returns TRUE, I look at `lpCompletionPortEntries[i]->lpOverlapped->Internal` because that is what the documentation says to do for `OVERLAPPED`. Please help me to understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR` is defined in winerror.h:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR
//
// MessageText:
//
// A notify change request is being completed and the information is not being returned in the caller's buffer. The caller now needs to enumerate the files to find the changes.
//
#define ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR            1022L
```

However, 1022 is 0x3FE.  0x10C is 268 instead, which is not an error code that `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` is supposed to return.  So if `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` is directly returning `STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR` instead of translating it into `ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR`, then that very well could be a bug inside of `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` itself, unless it is a typo in winerror.h instead.

`STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR` is used by some lower-level systems, like [`NT_TRANSACT_NOTIFY_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441586.aspx) and [`NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile()`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/File/NtNotifyChangeDirectoryFile.html), to indicate that the notification data is larger than the output buffer can hold.  That is what `ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR` means in `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`, as stated in its own documentation.

Some return values of other functions, like the `WaitFor...()` family of functions, and OverlappedIO/IOCP functions, map directly to `STATUS_...` codes internally, but are not documented as such because that is a private implementation detail.  For example, if you look in winbase.h, there are a couple of dozen common return codes, like `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, `WAIT_IO_COMPLETION`, `STILL_ACTIVE`, and various `EXCEPTION_...`, that map directly to `STATUS_...` values.

That does not appear to be the case in this situation, though.  [According to MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113996), `STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR`is indeed supposed to map to `ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR`, so this would appear to be a bug:

> When a kernel-mode driver is called because of an input/output (I/O) request from the Win32 subsystem, the status code returned by the kernel- mode driver will be translated to the status code's corresponding Win32 error code. The following table shows the mapping from the Windows NT status codes to Win32 error codes.
>
> ```
> WINDOWS NT STATUS CODE                  WIN32 ERROR CODE
> ------------------------------------------------------------------
> ...
> STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR                  ERROR_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR
> ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the additional confirmation. I thought I was going mad (not the first time). Any idea how I would go about poking around Microsoft for a fix?