# ReadDirectoryChangesW stops working on large amount of Files

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I'm using the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` together with the `IOCompletionQueue` to receive notifications if new files are added to a specific folder.

The Problem i'm currently facing is that if a huge batch copy operation happens (around 800 Files) my Program stopped working.

I debugged the program and recognized that it always fail when calling `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`. The Function call returns with a `TRUE` but the passed in variable `lpNumberOfBytesTransfered` is set to `0`.

Here is the Code that i used (i'm also open for any suggestions and help because i'm not that expert on the Windows API and ReadDirectoryChangesW)

```cpp
//FileIOAdapterImpl
HandlePtr FileIoAdapterImpl::CreateIoCompletionPortWrapper() {
  HandlePtr io_handle{ CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, 0, 0) };
  return io_handle;
}


bool FileIoAdapterImpl::AssociateWithFileHandle(HANDLE directory, HANDLE existing_completion_port) {
  return CreateIoCompletionPort(directory, existing_completion_port, (ULONG_PTR)directory, 1);
}

bool FileIoAdapterImpl::GetQueuedCompletionStatusWrapper(HANDLE completion_token,
  LPDWORD bytes_transferred, PULONG_PTR completion_key, LPOVERLAPPED* overlap) {
  return GetQueuedCompletionStatus(completion_token, bytes_transferred, completion_key, overlap, 16);

}

HandlePtr FileIoAdapterImpl::CreateFileWrapper(const std::string& path) {
  HandlePtr dir_handle{
    CreateFileA(path.c_str(), FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL)
  };

  return dir_handle;
}
bool FileIoAdapterImpl::ReadDirectoryChangesWrapper(HANDLE directory, std::vector<std::byte>& buffer, LPDWORD bytes_returned, OVERLAPPED* overlapped) {
  return ReadDirectoryChangesW(directory, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME, bytes_returned, overlapped, nullptr);
}
```

This class is just a wrapper around the the WindowsAPI Functions that i use (for testing/mocking purpose). The `HandlePtr` is just a `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter to call the `CloseHandle` Function.

```cpp
//ModernDirectoryWatcher.h
class ModernDirectoryWatcher {
public:
  using Callback = std::function<void(const std::string& filename)>;

  ModernDirectoryWatcher(const std::filesystem::path& input_directory, std::vector<std::string> file_types, Callback callback, FileIOAdapterPtr io_wrapper = std::make_shared<FileIoAdapterImpl>());

  explicit operator bool() const {
    return is_valid_;
  }

  bool watch();

  void stop();

private:

  bool event_recv();
  bool event_send();
  void handle_events();
  bool has_event() const {
    return event_buf_len_ready_ != 0;
  }
  bool is_processable_file(const std::filesystem::path& path) const;

  Poco::Logger& logger_{ Poco::Logger::get("ModernDirectoryWatcher") };
  std::filesystem::path input_directory_;
  std::vector<std::string> file_types_{};
  Callback callback_;
  FileIOAdapterPtr win_io_api_wrapper_;
  HandlePtr path_handle_;
  HandlePtr event_completion_token_;
  unsigned long event_buf_len_ready_{ 0 };
  bool is_valid_{ false };
  OVERLAPPED event_overlap_{};
  std::vector<std::byte> event_buf_{ 64 * 1024 };
};
```

```cpp
//ModernDirectoryWatcher.cpp
ModernDirectoryWatcher::ModernDirectoryWatcher(const std::filesystem::path& input_directory,
  std::vector<std::string> file_types, Callback callback, FileIOAdapterPtr io_wrapper)
  : input_directory_(input_directory),
  file_types_(std::move(file_types)),
  callback_(std::move(callback)),
  win_io_api_wrapper_(std::move(io_wrapper)) {

  path_handle_ = win_io_api_wrapper_->CreateFileWrapper(input_directory_.string());

  if (path_handle_.get() != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    poco_information(logger_, "Create Completition Token");
    event_completion_token_ = win_io_api_wrapper_->CreateIoCompletionPortWrapper();
  }

  if (event_completion_token_.get() != nullptr) {
    poco_information(logger_, "Associate with the FileHandle");
    is_valid_ = win_io_api_wrapper_->AssociateWithFileHandle(path_handle_.get(), event_completion_token_.get());
  }
}

bool ModernDirectoryWatcher::watch() {
  poco_information(logger_, "Start Watching...");
  if (is_valid_) {
    poco_information(logger_, "Receive Events");
    event_recv();

    while (is_valid_ && has_event()) {
      poco_information(logger_, "There are still events to process...");
      event_send();
    }

    while (is_valid_) {
      ULONG_PTR completion_key{ 0 };
      LPOVERLAPPED overlap{ 0 };
      bool complete = win_io_api_wrapper_->GetQueuedCompletionStatusWrapper(event_completion_token_.get(), &event_buf_len_ready_, &completion_key, &overlap);
      if (complete && event_buf_len_ready_ == 0) {
        poco_error(logger_, "Error"); // HERE THE ERROR IS PRINTED 
      }
      if (complete && overlap) {
        poco_information(logger_, "Handle the events");
        handle_events();
      } else if (int err_code = GetLastError() != 258 && !complete) {
        poco_error(logger_, "Error");
      }
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

void ModernDirectoryWatcher::handle_events() {
  while (is_valid_ && has_event()) {
    poco_information(logger_, "Send Event");
    event_send();
    poco_information(logger_, "Receive Events");
    event_recv();
  }
}

void ModernDirectoryWatcher::stop() {
  poco_notice(logger_, "Stop the Watcher");
  is_valid_ = false;
}

bool ModernDirectoryWatcher::event_recv() {
  event_buf_len_ready_ = 0;
  DWORD bytes_returned = 0;
  memset(&event_overlap_, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
  poco_information(logger_, "Call the ReadDirectoryChanges");
  auto read_ok = win_io_api_wrapper_->ReadDirectoryChangesWrapper(path_handle_.get(), event_buf_, &bytes_returned, &event_overlap_);

 
  if (!event_buf_.empty() && read_ok) {
    event_buf_len_ready_ = bytes_returned > 0 ? bytes_returned : 0;
    poco_information_f1(logger_, "Event Buffer Len: %?d", event_buf_len_ready_);
    return true;
  }

  if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
    poco_error(logger_, "Error Pending IO Received stopping...");
    event_buf_len_ready_ = 0;
    is_valid_ = false;
  } else {
    poco_error_f1(logger_, "Error Code: %?d", GetLastError());
  }
  return false;
}

bool ModernDirectoryWatcher::event_send() {
  auto buf = reinterpret_cast<FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*>(event_buf_.data());
  if (is_valid_) {
    while (buf + sizeof(FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION) <= buf + event_buf_len_ready_) {
      poco_information(logger_, "Get valid Buffer...");
      auto filename = input_directory_ / std::wstring{ buf->FileName, buf->FileNameLength / 2 };
      if ((buf->Action == FILE_ACTION_ADDED || buf->Action == FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME) && is_processable_file(filename)) {
        callback_(filename.string());
      }

      if (buf->NextEntryOffset == 0) {
        break;
      }

      buf = reinterpret_cast<FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*>(reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(buf) + buf->NextEntryOffset);

    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

bool ModernDirectoryWatcher::is_processable_file(const std::filesystem::path& path) const {
  std::string extension = path.extension().string().erase(0, 1);
  extension = Poco::toLower(extension);
  return std::find(file_types_.begin(), file_types_.end(), extension) != file_types_.end();
}
```

I start that Watcher as a thread from my application like this:

```cpp
ModernDirectoryWatcher directory_watcher{dir, ftypes, [this](const std::string& filename) {...})}
std::thread watcher_thread = std::thread{&ModernDirectoryWatcher::watch, &directory_watcher}
```

If i copy a greater amount of files (~800) Files to the watched Directory the code prints out the Error and then if i add again files (just one for example) the file is not recognized anymore. I know that this happens because i check in the `has_event` Function if the `event_buf_len_ready_` is greater then `0` what should normally be the case if the `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` is returning `TRUE`. But if i remove that check i start getting garbage out of the Buffer.

EDIT:

On thing i saw during the debugging. If i set a breakpoint inside the `if (complete && event_buf_len_ready_ == 0)` and take a look at the `OVERLAPPED` Structure i saw that the `internal` attribute has the value 268. But i did a quick `net helpmsg 268` but it did not found an errormessage to that number.

Comment: probably you got `STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR` (*This indicates that a notify change request is being completed and that the information is not being returned in the caller's buffer.*) and you not need call `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` better use `BindIoCompletionCallback`

Comment: look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801950/getqueuedcompletionstatusex-readdirectorychangesw

Comment: @RbMm i think it is the same error like in the mentioned link but it is not the `STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR` i also edited the question to mention the information there too

Comment: -no. It is exactly `STATUS_NOTIFY_ENUM_DIR` which value is 268

Comment: ok yes that would make sense if the buffer overflows then a manual check of the folder would make sense.

Comment: however your code far from best, you not need `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`, not need create any threads, etc. code can be more nice

Comment: @RbMm i'm open for any suggestions what can be improved :) so please give some advices

Comment: as possible example - https://gist.github.com/rbmm/d81717283e2ca33828be34d5a8edbcf0

Answer (score 1):

This is documented behavior.

```
When you first call ReadDirectoryChangesW, the system allocates a buffer to
store change information. This buffer is associated with the directory handle until
it is closed and its size does not change during its lifetime. Directory changes
that occur between calls to this function are added to the buffer and then
returned with the next call.

If the buffer overflows, ReadDirectoryChangesW will still return true, but the
entire contents of the buffer are discarded and the lpBytesReturned parameter
will be zero, which indicates that your buffer was too small to hold all of the
changes that occurred.
```

In this case, you have to assume that the change is so big that re-reading the directory from scratch is the better approach.

Comment: I also thought about that but what is the maximum size of the buffer that i can pass to the `ReadDirectoryChangesW`? Currently i create the buffer like that: `std::vector<std::byte> buffer{64*1024}`